# Mark directory as Excluded, but don't remove it from project

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, intellij-idea

I've included some library files in my page:

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

I've marked the folder lib as Excluded in IntelliJ IDEA, because I've wanted to hide this folder from the search results in IntelliJ. But now my webpage cann't find this folder as well and angularjs and jquery doesn't work.

Is there a way to mark directory as excluded from the search results in intellij, but don't hide it from other files? And I'm not interested in creating custom search scope.

I'm using web.xml, maybe I can put there some dependency to this folder, so it will be always loaded? Or I can edit IntelliJ configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the directory as a library. Go to `Project Settings` and then `Libraries`. Then choose one of the attach options. I am not sure whether you should pick `Attach Files and Directories`, `Attach Debug Version` or `Attach Release Version`.
[image: Attach Files in IntelliJ Library]

When you search select `Custom` and then `Project Files` from the Scope section and that should exclude your new library.

[image: Only Search for Project Files]